# Thunderbird/Firefox with shared profiles (Lubuntu+WinXP)

Tags: firefox, windows, thunderbird, lubuntu

I use Thunderbird and Firefox both on WinXP and Lubuntu 11.10. The profile folders are on the NTFS-partition of Windows and I'm sure that I've edited the profile paths correctly. Windows doesn't show any problems but Lubuntu shows the error dialog saying that another instance of Thunderbird/Firefox is already running..."

The funny thing is, that as soon as I've opened the profile folders in my explorer, firefox and thunderbird can be started. I don't have to change any files or something (Have made some experiments with .parentlock)

Do you have an idea how I could solve this problem, as I don't want to open the profile folders after every reboot.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the device with the shared folder mounted at startup ? If no, add-it to `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: how can I find the required information in fstab (especially the last three columns)? /dev/sdb1 /media ext3 defaults 1 2

Answer (score 0):

If the windows partition is mounted properly and you get this message, you had the thunderbird in Windows opened and the message is correct to avoid conflicts in the profile. Try booting windows and close it properly before you reboot. the file "lock" is created when you launch thunderbird and deleted when closed properly. So you may try to delete this file.